# Outgoing proxy connection

Tags: proxy, http-proxy

I am wondering whether I am able to setup a proxy only for outgoing connection but not for incoming connections

Please see the image below for a more detailed overview:!

[image]

or this one:

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Welcome to Information Security. Any more information on the requirement ?

Comment: Thank-you.The proxy would most likely be http or socket.

Answer (score 0):

This MIGHT be possible but you'll have to design build and implement it and then get others to use it.

Real quick:
The purpose of a proxy is to anonymise your data and/or only let it out at a secure point.

By using any of your proposed set-ups you'll end up receiving the data directly

How connections work:
When you have an outgoing request (when using tcp) you must also get a reply.
To get this reply the target needs a return address, and tcp isn't equipped with a reply to address but just uses the sender to reply.

Even if you get tcp to use a return address you'll completely brick the sessions because your router, pc or even browser has not a single clue what to do with this returning connection...
This is why if you expect incoming connections without an existing session (listening server) you need to use NAT which again if you open your browser to any input causes huge security porblems...

So concluding:
If you want to evade sending large (netflix) data over your proxy, just use an exception and allow it to go over your clear connection.

Comment: I'm in Australia and Netflix checks the IP address to see whether or not the user is from a UK or US location.If I use an exception wouldn't it cause Netflix to see my real location,thus blocking me.

Comment: Then you'll be stuck with proxies, I only have experience using proxpn, when you use a premium account there's no issues hd streaming. http://www.vpntopten.com/vpn-reviews/proxpn-review-speed-test